# Download container for an app from iPhone using Xcode command line

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed an iOS app, this app saves some of the log, that appears in the applications container. I can download this container using Xcode > Device > Select App > Download Container menu option.

Then I can see my log file in  directory `..../AppData/Documents/mylog.log`

Basically process describe here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/manage_containers.html

However I want to automate this, is there way to download an applications container using Xcode via command line?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Doing automatically no, but you can download it using Xcode

Answer (score 11):

There is a project called [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) on github. https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy

> // Download your app's Documents, Library and tmp folders
>   ios-deploy --bundle_id 'bundle.id' --download --to MyDestinationFolder
>
> // List the contents of your app's Documents, Library and tmp folders
>   ios-deploy --bundle_id 'bundle.id' --list
>
> // Download the Documents directory of the app *only*
>   ios-deploy --download=/Documents --bundle_id my.app.id --to ./my_download_location

Also, if you have a jailbreaked phone, you would have the most flexibility of do anything relative to file operations.
For example you could copy files using tools like 'scp', 'rsyn';

Comment: Provide context for links

*Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.* - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
Apparently, the link popularity doesn't matter to SO's guidelines ;)

Comment: It seems that ios-deploy isn't maintained anymore and it doesn't work with WiFi-connected devices (like the 4K AppleTV, at least for downloading files)