# How do I programmatically download an iOS Application's Container from a connected device

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcrun

I am aware of how to download an app container of a connected iOS device (not a simulator device) using the Xcode UI (via the Devices and Simulators view).  I am curious if there is a way to download a container using one of the Xcode command line tools.

I did see a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787212/download-container-for-an-app-from-iphone-using-xcode-command-line) with an answer that references a GitHub tool, [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy), that may be able to perform this task , but I was looking for a native solution to use first.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice

Comment: Any programatic way to achieve this ?Also May be the scenario multiple devices connected and choosing among them

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a.masri for the suggestion.  I ended up going with [ios-deploy](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy).  It suited my needs and is actively maintained.  It seems that [mobile device](https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice) is somewhat stale.